# Unable to connect remote db2 with node js

Tags: node.js, db2

I am trying to connect remote ibm db2 with node js in mac machine but I'm getting following error

```js
[Error: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968
] {
  error: '[node-ibm_db] SQL_ERROR',
  sqlcode: -1598,
  message: '[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968\n',
  state: '42968'
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to connect

```js
function db2Connection() {
  var ibmdb = require('ibm_db');
var connStr = "DATABASE=dbname;HOSTNAME=mydb.ibm.com;UID=userid;PWD=password;PORT=447;PROTOCOL=TCPIP";

ibmdb.open(connStr, function (err,conn) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  
  conn.query('SELECT * FROM T_Name FETCH FIRST 6 ROWS ONLY', function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(data);

    conn.close(function () {
      console.log('done');
    });
  });
});
}

db2Connection();
```

I went through some docs regarding that error but did not get any solution. Can anyone help on how to achieve this.

Comment: @mao Thanks for the reply. No I'm not connecting to i-series(as/400), it is z. And currently using node-ibm_db driver and version is "^2.7.0"..Yeah port is open to connect to the target hostname.

Comment: you may be using the clidriver (Db2 CLI driver) that gets installed by default (unless you have a previously installed Db2 CLI driver __AND__ set IBM_DB_HOME environment variable before installing node-ibm_db.). There are issues with recent builds of clidriver. You may want to try with older builds of clidriver (available from fix central), or install either the Db2-runtime client or Data ServerClient first , point IBM_DB_HOME to installation location. uninstall and re-install node-ibm_db.

Comment: @mao currently I am getting an error related to licensing, So the problem is not with respective driver right?

Comment: With IBM proprietary drivers, CLI access to Db2-for-Z is not free. You will need a db2-connect license file (with matching or higher version to your Db2-for-Z) in the license subdirectory of the clidriver installation, or connect via a Db2-gateway, or connect to a subsystem that is configured with db2connectactivate to avoid client-side licensing.  If you still get issues, refer to my previous comment.

Comment: @mao Thank you so much..Yeah i will try to follow the same